# Is a failing MATLAB license a try/catch exception?

Tags: matlab

Sometimes I loose a toolbox license while running a MATLAB simulation taking several hours. The simulation then stops, I get an error message like:

- License checkout failed
- License Manager Error -5
- Cannot find a license for Communication_Toolbox.

but there is no red error-text you normally get when there's an error in the MATLAB code itself.

Since this license error is not reproducable easily, does anybody know if it is an exception that can be caught within a try/catch? I could then maybe catch it, check the error-message for the word 'license' and keep trying until I get a license again and continue.

**Edit**: what apparently happens is that every couple of hours the flexlm license server is reset, if someone else then grabs a license before my already running script does, then my scrip is aborted. Or maybe my script tries to check the license while the license server is restarting...

Comment: _"Since this license error is not reproducable easily"_ Use a toolbox you don't have license for.

Comment: @Thomas. Our company has a licence for (as far as I know) every toolbox....

Comment: If you know which functions are causing this issue, you could call them up-front for some trivial input to get the license check-out on startup, which might then persist for the duration of your run

Comment: @Wolfie, "_which might then persist for the duration of your run_". That's just the problem. My script runs for hours calling these toolbox functions at least every few seconds, but suddenly the license dissapears... Probably because the license server is reset every 4 hours or so, and that's why I need to know if the license error can be caught in a try/catch.

Comment: This is not standard behaviour, you should check with either Mathworks support or your institutions IT license manager support.

Comment: Why would the license server be reset every four hours? Complain to your IT, get them to stop doing that.

Comment: Since you have every toolbox, you have the MATLAB Compiler too, right? You could compile your simulation code into a stand-alone executable. You can then run that without any licenses at all.

Comment: @Cris: we have hundreds of employees using MATLAB on a regular bases, IT wants to make sure that licenses are not kept too long by one person. They say I have to buy individual licenses for my needs.... That policy will not change.

Comment: @Cris. Compiling will also be a project on itself I guess, I would have to create a build-environment on the Linux High Performance Cluster where the simulations must run. A script which first let's MATLAB compile and then run the result, I'll keep it in mind. Nice idea!

Comment: this is what we call a try/catch-22 ...

Comment: "I would have to create a build-environment on the Linux High Performance Cluster where the simulations must run." That's not necessary, unless you modify the scripts on the fly (which sounds dubious, honestly). You can build the MATLAB executable on your own computer, then copy it to the cluster and run it there. As long as there's the same version of MATLAB installed there, it should work. I don't think the executables are platform-specific, except for the part that extracts the package. You can do that manually using `unzip`. At least, this is how it used to work 10 years ago... :)

Comment: @Cris Luengo. Thanks for the additional info. I have send an email to our IT department if such a solution could be implemented on the HPC. In that case, users do not have to compile themselves nor have to keep track of the 'correct MATLAB version'. It can then be available as a service on the HPC itself: upload your MATLAB script, it will be compiled and then run. It also has a huge advantage for sharing MATLAB licenses: they are only required to be shortly available during compile, then the simulation can run for days without licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just build the try/catch into the code and indeed the license error can be caught. The following represents a function which is called many times in my script and relies on several toolbox licenses. If a license is lost due to license server resets or some other reason, it waits for a minute and tries again. I don't care if the script has to wait an extra hour when running overnight...

```
function sim_data = get_sim_results(link, AWGN_SNR_dB)

while true
    try
        sim_data = get_sim_results_worker(link, AWGN_SNR_dB);
        break
    catch ME
        fprintf('Exception caught\n%s\n%s\n', ME.identifier, ME.message)
        pause(60)
    end
end
```